# Add, remove class on follow the button in carousel jQuery

Tags: jquery, carousel

How to change this line from 100px to 100%?

```
.animate({marginLeft:-100*(parseInt(integer)-1)})
```

And how to add, remove class on to ***.pic li*** and ***.title a*** follow the button in the carousel

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/04dsr8wn/3/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.trig span').click(function() {
    var integer = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('.carousel-box .pic').animate({
      marginLeft: -100 * (parseInt(integer) - 1)
    })
    $('.trig span').each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('on');
      if ($(this).hasClass('button' + integer)) {
        $(this).addClass('on')
      }
    });
  });
  Next();
  setInterval(function() {
    Next();
  }, 6000);
});

function Next() {
  var _next = false;
  $('.trig span').each(function() {
    if (_next) {
      $(this).addClass('on');
      _next = false;
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('on')) {
      _next = true;
      $(this).removeClass('on')
    }

  });
  if (_next)
    $(".trig span:eq(0)").addClass("on");

  var activeIndex = parseInt($(".on").attr("rel"));
  $('.carousel-box .pic').animate({
    marginLeft: -100 * (parseInt(activeIndex) - 1)
  });
}
```

```css
.panel {
  width: 705px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.panel .pic {
  width: 2820px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 80px;
}

.panel .scrollx {
  width: 705px;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #b0b0b0;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.button1,
.button2,
.button3,
.button4 {
  background: #999;
  padding: 6px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.on {
  background: #111;
  padding: 6px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  outline: none;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel-box">
  <div class="panel">
    <ul class="pic">
      <li class="scrollx on">1 Lorem Dolor Ipsum...</li>
      <li class="scrollx">2 Lorem Dolor Ipsum...</li>
      <li class="scrollx">3 Lorem Dolor Ipsum...</li>
      <li class="scrollx">4 Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit amet ....</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="title">
      <a href="#" class="on">title 1</a>
      <a href="#" class="">title 2</a>
      <a href="#" class="">title 3</a>
      <a href="#" class="">title 4</a>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <ul class="trig">
    <span class="button1 on" rel="1"></span>
    <span class="button2" rel="2"></span>
    <span class="button3" rel="3"></span>
    <span class="button4" rel="4"></span>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your carousel does not change image either

Comment: If I remove the class on in html in ***.pic li*** and ***.title a*** it will run. http://jsfiddle.net/04dsr8wn/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your first question:
You can convert to a string and add an `%` sign like so:

```
let w = -100*(parseInt(integer)-1);
$('.carousel-box .pic').animate({marginLeft:w+"%"})
```

To make your `Next` function work, change the code to the following:

```
$('.trig span').click(function(){
  let newPage = $(this).attr('rel');
  Next(newPage);
});
  Next();
  setInterval ( function(){Next();}, 6000 );
});

function Next(num){

    let maxPages = $(".trig span").length;
    let currPage = parseInt($(".trig span.on").attr("rel"));
    let nextPage = (num === undefined) ? currPage+1 : num;

    if(nextPage > maxPages)
        nextPage = 1;

    $('.pic li.on').removeClass("on");
    $('.title a.on').removeClass("on");
    $(".trig span.on").removeClass("on");

    $('.pic li').slice(nextPage-1, nextPage).addClass("on");
    $('.title a').slice(nextPage-1, nextPage).addClass("on");
    $('.trig span').slice(nextPage-1, nextPage).addClass("on");

    let w = -100*(parseInt(nextPage)-1);
    $('.carousel-box .pic').animate({marginLeft:w+'%'}); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Thanks to your answer, I solved the first question

Comment: You are welcome. Take a look at the modified `Next`function above.

Comment: I want class="on" to be added to <li> and <a>. It moves according to the button1,2,3,4 as in this illustrated html code: https://jsfiddle.net/678uv21n/

Comment: Ok, sorry for that, I modified my answer.

Comment: I can't believe it worked. I have a small problem this would like to ask you. Why style="margin-left: 100%;" It does not jump immediately up like this picture: https://imgur.com/a/Hiyshfi. I want it to jump immediately from 0 to 100%, 200% ... like this picture: https://imgur.com/a/0uM9B6k

Comment: I found another problem. Click on button. class=on does not return at < li > and < a >. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/04dsr8wn/8/

Comment: For an immediately appearance of the image on button click, just replace `.animate` with `.css`. Like so: `$('.carousel-box .pic').css({marginLeft:w+"%"})`

Comment: Take a look at the button event handler now. With this modification you always use the Next function for image positioning. No duplicated code.

Comment: You are a genius. Now it works perfectly like charm. Thank you very much for answering my question.

Comment: Sorry you. Another question. I encountered the phenomenon of clicking on the button sometimes it was blinking images repeatedly or immediately transferring images. 
Demo: https://imgur.com/a/jUCxHhr
http://jsfiddle.net/04dsr8wn/9/